# ISstyle Available not working with fonts

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, fonts

I have two drop down lists(DropFont,DropFontSize) and a textbox(txtSample) one for font name and the other for font size and now if I select the font name from the drop down list the text in the text box should change with the desired font name and size.But when I change some fonts it gives me error stating that the font dosen't support "Regular".

So I have been trying to modify as shown below but now it gives me error that font property is read-only.

Here is my code:

```
 Try
                    ' Compose the font style.
                    Dim font_style As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular
                    If Bold.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Bold
                    If Italic.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Italic
                    If Underline.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Underline
                    If StrikeOut.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Strikeout

                    ' Get the font size.
                    Dim font_size As Single = 8
                    Try
                        font_size = Single.Parse(DropFontSize.SelectedValue)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try

                    ' Get the font family name.
                    Dim family_name As String = "Times New Roman"
                    If Not (DropFont.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
                        family_name = DropFont.SelectedItem.ToString
                    End If
                    ' Make the new font.
                    Dim new_font As New Font(family_name, font_size, font_style)


                Catch

                End Try
```

Now setting the font like this:

```
txtsample.font=new_font// getting error stating that font property is read-only.
```

Comment: Personally, I'd add a css class to the element when needed that changes the font.

Comment: Can you explain me in detail as I'm using this text on the image as watermark.

Comment: What object type is `txtsample`?

Comment: Are you sure you are defining new_font so it is accessible where you are using it? (outside the try-catch block?). Does the following work?

`txtSample.font = New Font("Times New Roman", 8, FontStyle.Regular)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS` or `WebControl.Font` properties. You can't change(replace) the font property (as it is read only). If you want to draw an image then use CSS `background` property.